# Two-Tier Navigation Bar Incorrect Colors and Spacing

Tags: html, css, colors, html-table, navigationbar

First of all, here is a link to [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/ojmq4gpc/). Hopefully, I did it right. I want to make the boxes do something similar to what is in this picture:

[image]

When I hover over any of the choices in the navigation bar, I want:

- the color of the entire square to change to grey
- the spacing after every option in the drop down to be correct (nothing I do spaces them out from each other)
- after the square turns grey to stay within the black bar

To save you a click, here is the css for the navigation bar I have.

```
#nav_bar ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: .5em 0.5em;
    background-color: black;
}
#nav_bar li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav_bar a {
    padding: 1em 1.5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}
#nav_bar a.current {
    color: orange;
}
#nav_bar ul ul {
    display: none;
}
#nav_bar ul li {
    padding: .5em;
}
#nav_bar li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0%;
    top: 100%;
    padding: .5em;
}
#nav_bar ul:hover a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
#nav_bar ul ul:hover a:hover {
    background-color: gray;
}
```

The full HTML will be in the link above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To keep space between the options, use this code in your CSS

```
#nav_bar ul ul li a{
    display:block;
    padding : 0em 3.2em;
}
```

Also i so that in your code. when hovering the main nav bar it increases the size. 
if you do wont to fix that use the code below.
This code changes some properties in your padding for the list-item

```
#nav_bar a {
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes with code and structure of html . Please check the below HTML and CSS code

HTML code below :-

```
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="images/pumpkin.gif" alt="Pumpkin" width="85">
        <h2>The Halloween Store</h2>
        <h3>For the little Goblin in all of us!</h3>
    </header>
    <section>
        <nav id="nav_bar">
            <ul>
                <li id="home"><a href="index.html" class="current">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li id="products"><a href="">Product List</a>
                </li>
                <li id="personal"><a href="">Personal</a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropbtn">Decorating Items</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-content">
                        <a href="#">Outdoor</a>
                        <a href="#">Indoor</a>
                        <a href="#">TableTreats</a>
                    </div>
                </li>


                <li id="email"><a href="">Join Email</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:top;width=160px;">
                    <nav id="nav_list">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="products/props.html">Props</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="products/costumes.html">Costumes</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="products/special.html">Special FX</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="products/masks.html">Masks</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <main>
                        <h1>Welcome to my site.<br>Please come in and stay awhile.</h1>
                        <p>I started this web site because Halloween has always been my favorite holiday. But during the last year, I started selling some of my favorite Halloween products, and they've become quite a hit.</p>
                        <p>If you click on the Personal link, you can browse my favorite Halloween pictures, stories, and films. And if you join my email list, I will keep you up-to-date on all things Halloween.</p>
                        <h2>Product of the week</h2>
                        <a href="products/masks.html">
                            <img src="images/cat1.jpg" alt="Deranged cat"></img>
                            <br>
                        </a>
                        <a href="products/masks.html">20" Deranged cat</a>
                        <br>
                        <br>

                        <h3>My guarantee</h3>
                        <p>If you aren't completely satisfied with everything you buy from my site, you can return it for a full refund. <strong>No questions asked!</strong>
                        </p>
                    </main>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; 2016 Ben Murach</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS code Below :-

```
html {
    background-color: white;    
}
body  {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    padding: 0;
    border: 3px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 9px 18px 9px;
}
h1, h2, h3, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    color: white;
}
a:link, a:visited { 
    color: white; 
}


/* Header */
header { 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, orange 75%, black 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, orange 75%, black 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, orange 75%, black 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, white 0%, orange 75%, black 100%);
    padding: 30px; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
} 
header img { 
    float: left; 
    padding-right: 15px;  
} 
header h2 {
    font-size: 230%;
}
header h3 {
    font-size: 125%;
}

/* Main */
main {
    padding: 0px 25px 25px 25px;
}
main h1 { 
    font-size: 140%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
main h1:first-letter { 
    font-size: 240%;
}
main h2 {
    font-size: 125%;
    margin: .8em 0 .5em 0;
}
main h3 {
    font-size: 110%;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
main p {
    margin-bottom: .5em;
}
main ul {
    margin-top: 0;
}
main a {
    font-weight: bold;
}



#nav_list ul {
    padding-top: 1.25em;
    padding-left: .8em;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav_list li {
    width: 125px;
    margin-bottom: .5em;
    background-color: orange;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
#nav_list li a {
    display: block;
    padding: .5em .5em .5em .5em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}




section {
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;
}
#nav_bar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: black;
}

#nav_bar li {
    float: left;
}

li a, .dropbtn {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_bar li a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: grey;
}

#nav_bar li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: white;
     background-color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

li .current {

    color: orange;
}

/* Footer */
footer { 
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    padding: 15px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, orange 25%, white 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, orange 25%, white 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, orange 25%, white 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, black 0%, orange 25%, white 100%);
} 
footer p {
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: center;
}
```